# How do I write string-data from a zip to a new zip in Swift

Tags: json, swift, string, zip, file-manager

I receive a zip file in a json as a String(utf-8). The zip contains some pngs. I want to use this String and make a zip file from this String and save it as a file on the phone.

However when I try to convert the String into data with base64 and write it to a zip file, it will create a zip file but you can't really open it.

When I download the container of my app in xcode (window -> Devices & Simulators -> myApp -> download container) it shows me the file but when I try to manually unzip it, it will create a new file with .cpgz extension. You can see this in the link below.

[here is an image of the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQQQw.png)

The Json-String looks like this:

```
"data:application/x-zip-compressed;base64,$ThisIsAVeryLongCrypticString$"
```

I have both tried to cut the pre-String from the zip String: "data:application/x-zip-compressed;base64," and just used the long string to save the data and did the same with the pre-String (including the long String), but it still wouldn't work.

**My Code:**

```
            let fm = FileManager()
            guard let uuid = UUID(beCarModel.uuid) else {
                return
            }
            var zipPath = fm.temporaryDirectory
            zipPath.appendPathComponent(uuid.uuidString)
            zipPath.appendPathExtension("zip")

            if fm.fileExists(atPath: zipPath.path) {
                try? fm.removeItem(at: zipPath)
            }

            let newString = json.zip.replacingOccurrences(of: "data:application/x-zip-compressed;base64,", with: "")

            guard (try? newString.data(using: .utf8)?.base64EncodedData().write(to: zipPath)) != nil else {
                return
            }
```

Comment: Try using https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation --> Worked for me.

Comment: "I receive a zip file in a json as a String(utf-8)." wat. Why would you send a zip file as a json string?! https://i.imgur.com/lB5wmMp.png

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Also what he said. Does the file unzip fine when you build on device?

Comment: The zip is uploaded on a Server and unzips fine on it. it won't once it is downloaded and converted back to a zip file